# MySQL & Hibernate: performance of left outer join vs multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, join

I have two tables in MySQL, "apps" and "icons", each with about 750K rows. In Hibernate I was modeling them like:

```
public class App {
    @Basic
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "app")
    private Icon icon;
    // etc...
}

public class Icon {
    @Basic
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private App app;
    // etc...
}
```

When I added this relation I quickly ran into a performance problem- reading in a single App was taking > 1 second. I examined the SQL that Hibernate was producing and found it was joining like this:

```
select
    apps.id as app_id,
    apps.title as app_title,
    icons.id as icon_id,
    icons.name as icon_name
from
    apps
left outer join
    icons
        on apps.id=icons.app_id 
where
    apps.id="zyz";
```

I found that adding `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` to the annotation greatly sped up the performance, bringing it down to around 30ms for effectively the same result. Here's the produced SQL with the `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` annotation:

```
select
    apps.id as app_id,
    apps.title as title
from
    apps 
where
    apps.id="xyz";


select
    icons.id as icon_id,
    icons.name as icon_name
from
    icons
where
    icons.app_id="xyz";
```

Why is the left outer join so much slower? "Explain" on the joined query shows:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | apps  | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 767     | const |      1 |       | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | icons | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 783556 |       | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

So it's apparently visiting every row, vs a single row for the multiple-select query. Can't the join use the index that I have on icons.app_id?

PS: yes, I used "RESET QUERY CACHE" in-between timing runs.

**Update:** moved to a `bigint` primary key, used that to join the tables in instead of the `VARCHAR`, and performance of the join is now on par with the "multiple selects" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your explain, I believe the issue is with your schema at the database layer and not at the application layer.

The fact that the join to the icons table has no entry for `possible_keys` leads me to believe you are running a MyISAM storage engine or an InnoDB storage engine with no FK constraints. Also, a key length of 767 strikes me as unusual, I've only ever seen this value < 10.

- If the engine is MyISAM: Add an index to the `icons.app_id` column. And consider using an InnoDB engine so you can establish FK constraints so that you do not end up with orphaned rows.
- If the engine is InnoDB: Add a FK constraint to the `icons.app_id` which references `apps.id`. By adding a FK constraint not only are you ensuring your data doesn't become orphaned, you are also optimizing the joins between the tables because you are forced to create an index on both column.

Either of the solutions mentioned above should greatly improve your performance. Let me know how it goes.

You can read more info about some discussed topics using these links:

- [InnoDB Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html)
- [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

**-- Update --**

Here are some example alters when you are ready to add the INT columns, remember to do this on dev first and make sure this resolves the issue before pushing to production.

For the apps table:

```
 ALTER TABLE apps
     ADD COLUMN idi int(11) UNSIGNED auto_increment FIRST,
     DROP PRIMARY KEY,
     ADD PRIMARY KEY(idi);
```

For the icons table:

```
 ALTER TABLE icons
     ADD COLUMN app_idi int(11) UNSIGNED auto_increment AFTER app_id,
     ADD INDEX (app_idi ),
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (app_idi) REFERENCES apps(app_idi) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

These alters are demonstrative only, but should be enough to get you started in the right direction. You can read up on the MySQL docs I posted about Foreign Key Constraints for more information. Now, with the FK constraint setup between apps and icons, if any apps are deleted, and rows with icons matching `app.id` will also be deleted, ensuring you don't orphan any data. If you don't want to delete the associated rows in the `icons` table, you can change `ON DELETE CASCADE` to `ON DELETE NULL`, and they will be unlinked from the `apps` table, but still reside in the `icons` table.

Comment: Indeed, it's MyISAM, autogenerated from a legacy Hibernate app. There actually is already an index on icons.app_id. I'm interested in moving to InnoDB, especially if the performance is likely to improve, but I've read the opposite (perhaps misinformed?) The keys are VARCHAR(255) (again, bit of a Hibernate autogenerated mess). Would changing the PK to a more traditional integer type, instead of our business key help performance?  Much appreciate your time, thanks.

Comment: I've always found that using int datatypes perform better than non-int data types when it comes to indexing. One thing you could do is create an int PK on a new table, but still keep your old varchar key for legacy references. Then as you upgrade the app, try to use the new PK column instead. Can you post your table schemas? Might be able to offer some more insight.

Comment: Ya, that varchar PK is killing your performance. Do you have a dev version you can toy with? I'll post some alters you can use to add the columns necessary to test using int over varchar.

Comment: Sure do. It's a little hung up at the moment trying to convert my tables to InnoDB, but when it recovers I will try adding the int PKs. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I added some sample alters to help you out. They are demonstrative only, so be sure to think about what you are doing.

Comment: Hi, did you notice a performance increase switching from `varchar` to `int` datatypes for your joins?

Comment: Yes, see updated question.  I didn't exactly use your alters- I need to manually update the PKs to match based on the existing ids. But you got me going in the right direction, and once the PK was an int performance was reasonable again. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Love when a plan comes together </hannibal_smith>